# can any one tell me steps to use ajax-register module

Tags: users

can any one please tell me the steps to use ajax-register module for user login, user registration and change password in drupal 7.
which display user registration, user login, forget password forms in i-box.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers. Let me remind you that "Requests for tutorials" are on the list of things you should **not ask** here. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download & install [Ajax Register](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register).
2. Goto

   Admin -> Module -> Enable [Ajax Register]
3. Goto

   Admin -> Configuration -> Ajax Register

Update configuration setting as per you want.